# Equal Algebraic Expressions

Tags: calculus

By integration by parts, we know $\displaystyle \int x\sqrt{5-x}dx=x\frac{-2}{3}(5-x)^{3/2}-\frac{4}{15}(5-x)^{5/2}+C$.

The answer for this question in the back of the book is $\dfrac{2}{5}(5-x)^{5/2}-\dfrac{10}{3}(5-x)^{3/2}+C$. How can I manipulate the first equation to get the second one?

Comment: What did you try? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933

Comment: I'm not sure where to start which is my problem.

Comment: Calculate the difference of the two expressions. You may set $y=5-x$ to simplify the notations (so $x=5-y$),

Comment: It may help to graph these two functions to see if they really are off by a constant, and, if so, what that constant is.